# Drupal 8 Theming

Tags: theming

I am beginner with drupal 8 theming.

My Question is:
I have created a custom content type name project_images for making carousal SlideShow. It consists multiple images as a field. Now I want to retrieve all images in a custom region with twig templating how to access all images from project_images content.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the field that stores the multiple images ?

Is it an Image field or an Entity Reference field (Media Entity) ?

1. check [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd) if it's an image field
2. check [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image/issues/2856093#comment-12689671) if it's an Entity Reference field

The two methods will let you extract the value of the image field using a twig syntax.

Comment: Image Field Only